# Lots of open file handlers on deleted files in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins to run pipeline groovy scripts. One of the first step is a checkout via the checkout plugin. The checkout happens into the `<workspace>/source-repo` folder.

Now, when I do lsof (it is a linux machine) I get a lot of open file handlers like this:

```
java      16932     1000  567r      REG             202,80         91    7996215 <workspace>/source-repo@tmp/durable-a06b8b8d/output.txt (deleted)
```

They are building up over time ... Why? And what can i do?

Comment: I've got this problem too. Any luck resolving it? For me I've got a recurring job that runs every 5 minutes and these file handles are just going up and up and up and eventually I run out of open files and have to restart Jenkins. Not sure why these are not being closed.

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it seems to be related to `sh` in combination with `returnStdout: true`. So I replaced calls like this:

```
def ret = sh script: "command", returnStdout: true
```

with

```
sh "command > output.txt"
def ret = readFile "output.txt"
sh "rm output.txt"
```

Feels a bit hacky, but now I am fine.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. This is also the approach I ended up taking as I had also found that it was the returnStdout attribute of sh that was the culprit.
I've started a discussion on the subject here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/j8CfFDx25Bg
And put a comment on this ticket in Jira, could be worth voting on it or commenting with your experience:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43639?focusedCommentId=302114&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-302114

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed in the Durable Task Plugin since Version 1.14 (Jun 15 2017)

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43639